# How to setup base URL in codeigniter running on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: codeigniter, ubuntu-14.04

Installed LAMP stack. Right now I've extracted codeigniter files to /var/www/ci 
but while running on browser http://localhost/ci/ the welcome page doesn't display.

Comment: what error is showing?

Comment: when i type localhost/ci/index.php it says NOT FOUND

Comment: Append controller name at last...

Comment: What version of codeigniter?

Comment: codeigniter 3.0.3. and how am i supposed to set the base url? right now base URL is "http://localhost/ci/"

Comment: Have u followed the naming conventions??

Comment: Im new to ubuntu. what naming conventions?

Comment: is single php file is running properly

Comment: @ArunKumar, naming convention is of codeigniter not ubuntu...

Comment: When I Try to insert localhost/ci/index.php no welcome message. And I'm new to codeigniter as well. 
It says The requested URL /ci/index.php was not found on this server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found the answer. Have to enable the site.

In /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf file shud modified as follows:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot /var/www/
     ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
     <Directory /var/www/ci/>

         AllowOverride All

     </Directory>
     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>`

And this worked for me! Thanks all.

Comment: Thank you - this worked for me as well. I also had to modify by sites-enabled .conf file in the same manner to make it work for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ubuntu 14.04 the web server inside var/www/html, so move your folder into var/www/html/ci.

And open .htaccess file inside ci folder.paste the following code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /ci/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: On a fresh install there is not .htaccess in the root folder! So you don't need that.

Comment: Sure you do, this fixes most problems when combined with a correct base_url in settings.php. Setting a separate virtual host for each project is overkill. Also get rid of that index.php: CI always needs an .htaccess file to look good.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the base url in /application/config/config.php on line 26.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/';
```

If that doesn't solve the problem you have to post more informations.

Fresh codeigniter install?
No third party plugins?
No changes to routes? (in /application/config/routes.php)
No changes to the controller?
No changes to the view?

Do you get errors?
If not check if error reporting is on in the index.php (set it hard to development for testing)

Do you use Rewrite rules in an .htaccess in the /var/www/ci/ folder?

Do you autoload anything? libraries, models, languages, helpers ?

If you can't find anything, set this to 4:

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 4;
```

in /application/config/config.php on line 216.

The log file is written to /application/logs/.

Post that log, probably it helps.

Comment: Its a fresh codeigniter 3.0.3. 
I've jst extracted to /var/www/ci/
Base path is set already as u said. 
Still in the browser when I insert localhost/ci/index.php it says not found