# 404 Page Not Found when run Codeigniter project inside var/www/html/ on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, ubuntu-16.04, lamp

> I have installed LAMP (Linux, Apache2, MySQL, and PHP) stack.

I have a project directory named 'mahasiswa'. When i ran it on Windows 8 was working well (using XAMPP). Then, when i run it on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS inside `var/www/html/` is not working anymore.

The screen shot of the result :

[image: image of the error message]

Is there special configuration to run CodeIgniter project on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ?

:: Any help would be much appreciate. Thank you.

---

### EDIT

My configuration files :

1. **etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**

[image]

2. **etc/apache2/sites-available/mahasiswa.conf**

[image]

3. **etc/hosts**

[image]

4. **mahasiswa/.htaccess**

[image]

The current result on browser:

[image]

I don't know exactly what i've missing at this configuration. I've followed @eeya instruction / answer below. Any body can help me, please :D

Comment: Did you set a `virtual host configuration` (e.g mahasiswa.conf) on this directory? [/etc/apache2/sites-available]

Comment: What is the name of the index / home page?  You might need to configure Apache if it is not index.htm or index.html or index.php.  Also remember that  in Linux files are case-sensitive while in Windows they are not.

Comment: @eeya not yet .. how to set it and what is it for ?

Comment: Setting apache's `virtual host` is optional if you want multiple projects have different [configuration] (e.g location of the project / server name / server alias / etc.). In this case, I don't think you might need it for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your question in setting up the `apache` virtual host configuration: Here's how it goes. If you have [root] privilege, Open your [Terminal] and go to this directory: `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

Then create a new virtual host configuration, For now, we will name this configuration the name of your project.

`sudo vim mahasiswa.conf` or `sudo nano mahasiswa.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local.mahasiswa.com 
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mahasiswa
    <Directory /var/www/html/mahasiswa/>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

1) ServerName: serves as the the DNS (Think of it as another server name aside from http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1)

2) DocumentRoot: from the word itself, is your [project]'s directory (e.g /var/www/html/mahasiswa)

3) Directory: are used to enclose a group of directives that will apply only to the named directory, sub-directories of that directory, and the files within the respective directories. In this case, we wanted to place control access rights to a directory:

AllowOverride All (This can be either All or None)

Require all granted

Allow from all

You can learn more of this here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory

Going back, Once you've saved this new configuration, Go to your `/etc/hosts` (hosts file) (e.g `sudo vim /etc/hosts`) and add the ff:

127.0.0.1       localhost local.mahasiswa.com

Once you've saved these changes on your [hosts] file, Execute this command:

`sudo a2ensite mahasiswa.conf`

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`

This will now [enable] your new site configuration and enable the [url rewrite] module as well. Then execute this afterwards:

`sudo service apache2 reload`

From the command itself, it means you need to reload [apache2] thus the configuration takes affect afterwards.

Then try to access your new domain name: local.mahasiswa.com.
You should be able to see your `CI` pages you've needed.

For further reference, check [Digital Ocean] guide here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

Hope this helps for your case.

**Edit:** 
In naming the [controller] file(s) (e.g mahasiswa), You might need to set [UpperCase] instead of [lowercase] format to (e.g Mahasiswa)

Comment: it seems not clear to me whether to add `127.0.0.1 localhost local.mahasiswa.com` OR `ff: 127.0.0.1 localhost local.mahasiswa.com` on /etc/hosts file. Which one i should use ?

Comment: `127.0.0.1 localhost local.mahasiswa.com`. When you've open your [hosts] file, you can see that `127.0.0.1 localhost` is there already. Just add `local.mahasiswa.com` right next to `localhost`. This is generally apply to other OS (e.g Windows) as well. Take note that you've place this value the same `ServerName` you've provided on your `vhosts config` file

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. I've followed all you said. But, unfortunately my codeigniter project still doesn't work (404 Page Not Found still appear).

Comment: Hmm..If we may, can you add the [.htaccess] you've setup on your CI project on your question?

Comment: i've upload .htaccess image. You can see it now.

Comment: On your `.htaccess` file, Is there a reason why you've set `RewriteBase` to `/mahasiswa` instead of '/'?

Comment: I'm not sure. But, i followed this from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34018681/how-to-setup-base-url-in-codeigniter-running-on-ubuntu-14-04 (Asif Jafri Mohammad Fahim's answer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145309/discussion-between-eeya-and-ridoan-saleh-nasution).

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite

sudo systemctl restart apache2
```